# while im trying to build docker image for itx version 9 using my docker file, i getting '" apt-get install ksh' returned a non-zero code: 1" error

Tags: docker, wtx

[when im trying to build ITX version 9 docker image from my docker file getting below error, saying apt-get install ksh returned 0 code:1 , can anyone help me out of this.[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDMYr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running the install instruction inside a Dockerfile, in a non-interactive mode, you have to provide `--assume-yes` option

```
RUN apt-get install -y ksh
```

[apt-get manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)